# Typescript: variable function arguments depending on the preceding arguments

Tags: typescript, algorithm, generics, recursion, typescript-typings

This question must have been asked before, I'm almost certain of it. Yet:

1. I can't find any such question
2. Typescript has made major leaps in the recent past, thus the existing answers might be outdated.

Something that I commonly use in my code is spread operator for function arguments allowing me to take in a variable length array of arguments. What I'm trying to do now is create TS type defenition for a function where `arg1` type depends on `arg2` type, and `arg2` depends on `arg3`, and so on.

Very much like this in lodash https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/lodash/common/util.d.ts#L209

```
 flow<R2, R3, R4, R5, R6, R7>(f2: (a: ReturnType<T>) => R2, f3: (a: R2) => R3, f4: (a: R3) => R4, f5: (a: R4) => R5, f6: (a: R5) => R6, f7: (a: R6) => R7): Function<(...args: Parameters<T>) => R7>;
```

The lodash approach is obviously very limited and also maxes out (in this example) at 8 arguments. This is fine, and I can live with it, however, in 2021 is there a better, more recursive way? A way to do the same thing for a (theoretically) `infinite` number of arguments?

Please feel free to close the question and point me to an existing answer, if such exists and it's up to date.

Comment: I would consider changing one of the five tags to "algorithm" to increase relevant audience.

Answer (score 4):

With inference in conditional types, this is possible (albeit slightly ugly):

```js
// convenience alias
type Func = (...args: any[]) => any;

// check arguments in reverse
// since typescript doesn't like deconstructing arrays into init/last
type CheckArgsRev<T extends Func[]> =
    // get first two elements
    T extends [infer H1, infer H2, ...infer R]
        // typescript loses typings on the inferred types
        // so this gains them back
        ? H1 extends Func ? H2 extends Func ? R extends Func[]
            // actual check
            // ensures parameters of next argument extends return type of previous
            // you can substitute this with whatever check you want to add
            // just know that H1 is the current argument type and H2 is the previous
            // also if you change this to work with non-functions then change Func to an appropriate type
            // like unknown to work with all types
            ? Parameters<H1> extends [ReturnType<H2>]
                // it was a match, recurse onto the tail
                ? [H1, ...CheckArgsRev<[H2, ...R]>]
                : never // invalid type, become never for error
            : never : never : never // should never happen
        // base case, 0 or 1 elements should always pass
        : T;

// reverse a tuple type
type Reverse<T extends unknown[]> =
    T extends [infer H, ...infer R]
        ? [...Reverse<R>, H]
        : [];

// check args not in reverse by reversing twice
type CheckArgs<T extends Func[]> = Reverse<CheckArgsRev<Reverse<T>>>;

// make sure the argument passes the check
function flow<T extends Func[]>(...args: T & CheckArgs<T>) {
    console.log(args);
}

// this is invalid (since number cannot flow into a string)
flow((x: string) => parseInt(x, 10), (x: string) => x + "1");
// this is valid (number flows into number)
flow((x: string) => parseInt(x, 10), (x: number) => x + 1);
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=44&pc=1#code/PTAEGMHsDsDcFNoEtHnqAhgGyRgzgFAAuAngA7oBiArtOKALygAUAdOxgE4DmeAXJmgkA2gF0AlIwB8gkgG4CBEBAAW8cAGtMPagFtERPKCTRQneAk554SsHhNpQpCnnCckZIqAAmkeHmgAci8cDXRvdRg8Ik5qcCITbm1ODBIjEyJIY2QiYCx8ImJydABhNU0AQR48ACULAB4AFVB4AA8iRG8jGjoxGQYCUCHQZW54LwAzJCsvIgB3LPgseH1oQ0Hh5raO6C7QYRMJ+E5QAAkARgAabKOT04Ama-ZWQ+PQGtEN4eHlZ383DwhSDWIzORJGGBONQ3Y7mbxOYqEb7fZR4LJEFRIIzcDAmUFqXSgABGGE0X2RAH4zucWu1Ot1aPQqQ9aTs9j0me9WfTQByxOTkT8wKSiNRsKp1BoBYKRmBEHhqOYjGQuBh9B0rKBIBNQNBttpuHoDNzdkZzKLOKY-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)

Answer (score 2):

[Aplet's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65653716/10305477) is great! But it gives up the type information about the function array when you pass a wrong argument. An error that just says `Argument of type '(x: string) => number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.` when the error is actually originating from `(x: string) => string` isn't super helpful.

Unfortunately there doesn't really seem to be a robust method of doing this, but I'd still like to share my 2 cents-

```
type AnyFunc = (a: any) => any;

// Given a tuple of functions - deduce how much of it is flowable
type FlowFrom<T extends readonly AnyFunc[]> = T extends [(a: infer R) => any, ...AnyFunc[]]
    ? // Infer the argument type of the first function and pass it to `FlowFrom$`
      FlowFrom$<R, T>
    : // T was empty array
      [];

// Actual function that deduces how much of a tuple is flowable, taking previous return type and remaining functions
type FlowFrom$<R, T extends readonly [(a: R) => any, ...AnyFunc[]]> = T extends [
    (a: R) => infer R$,
    ...infer Tail
]
    ? Tail extends [(a: R$) => any, ...AnyFunc[]]
        ? // Valid, continue
          [(a: R) => R$, ...FlowFrom$<R$, Tail>]
        : // Tail has either been exhausted or invalid function has been found
        Tail extends [(a: any) => any, ...AnyFunc[]]
        ? // Invalid function found, append a correct function type so it points out the specific error
          // But make the appended function optional, the flow is still valid before this point
          [(a: R) => R$, (a: R$) => any] | [(a: R) => R$]
        : // Tail exhausted
          [(a: R) => R$]
    : // T is empty, exhausted tuple (impossible - apparently)
      [];
```

`FlowFrom` deduces a "flowable" tuple type from a given tuple of functions. Essentially, it extracts all the functions in the tuple that *will* flow into each other, stopping whenever it encounters a function that is no longer flowable or when the tuple has exhausted.

```
// All the functions in the tuple type are flowable - the return type is the same
let valid: FlowFrom<[(x: string) => number, (x: number) => number]>;
//  ^ [(a: string) => number, (a: number) => number]

// First function won't flow into the second one - stop at first one
let invalid: FlowFrom<[(x: string) => number, (x: string) => number]>;
//  ^ [(a: string) => number, (a: number) => any] | [(a: string) => number]
```

This means, when you try to assign `[(x: string) => parseInt(x, 10), (x: string) => x + '1']` to `invalid`, you get a nice error-

```
let invalid: FlowFrom<[(x: string) => number, (x: string) => number]> = [
    (x: string) => parseInt(x, 10),
    (x: string) => x + '1',
];
//  ^ Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'
```

But, you can still assign the stuff before that breaking point-

```
let reducedButCorrect: FlowFrom<[(x: string) => number, (x: string) => number]> = [
    (x: string) => parseInt(x, 10),
];
```

(in case you don't want this behavior, as in - being able to still assign everything before the breaking point when a breaking point is present, remove the union type from `FlowFrom$`, `[(a: R) => R$, (a: R$) => any] | [(a: R) => R$]` -> `[(a: R) => R$, (a: R$) => any]`)

You can now use it like-

```
declare function flow<T extends readonly AnyFunc[]>(...args: T & FlowFrom<T>): unknown;

// Valid
flow(
    (x: string) => parseInt(x, 10),
    (x: number) => Boolean(x),
    (x: boolean) => Number(x)
);

// Invalid
flow(
    (x: string) => parseInt(x, 10),
    (x: number) => Boolean(x),
    (x: string) => Number(x)
);
//  ^ Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'string'
```

Try all of this out on [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggdiAYgVzgYygXigCgIYBcUeCAlFgHzEIDcAUHQPSNQDiAlgG4RzFTDIwAG2gB7AGZRxqNMHai4AZygBaKABMI65GmgALUQHcoAWx16oEqO2DXl4oUbwAjEXVCQoiR4cQAnURMAHgAVKAgAD2AedWU-CDx1BSEQWAQUdABtAF0qbDDI6LhYqEz8InY4cQg-KAAlckwqEhAAGigAOi74JBkc7LooIagAfihmKABJKpr+PWg8PwBzZBMeWw8xSWB5qXY-RVtpdDkFanUoMDxFZRt+USgAA28jf0CAEkfB4aGX3wCTO8gnV2iEKN8hkQJmFDNdwiYwKBiH4-HgQBDhjl6EwWDBZMg8EIpDJTrwdnhbJptLplAZjGY0BYrHh+IIRHYpD4XCJ2sA8ABrSpLS7xTjyZBxCACPxk8ALYpQeImPCVIXEk7yJTuOVeHxvQHA0HhKIxSWJZKpMqEeqNZoIdpdDo9DJofp5KAFE3FZSZDHlG2UawzWp1d6tDGOyrVWohFVCOgDH5jWPsImFU2lf2h23UNqdbrpPrZRM-YZjCYANUJ7HU7TQCjkcGQEAxpcz1oagdDDq6f31QO7HrjFBLbahLBTRL0cIgNnmtWcEB4xunEuiF1EtUqnGrF2Osk1UGnykXy-EolQ6lbw0nxqKJStRBaOZaPadhayxevQ3LLGmO6EGt1QPM5z0vdo8DASAFRZesUQgWRgNJfgdUUB47jAURKmAZQLw2XZFEgNB2HEdgMBqAI-G-YYJgAIWQWxlX5aAdgWKCYi0JDD1ERFNUJXldgcIwOUOVMiQAoDF3PeI5nYZRMOw6ihkfAMmnqMNcA7d4XwQbIoAAH3bIhOzU0NR1Lcch1TFc8DXLQlKM1SqDMjFLLCOT4URPNIlXQ5OIEYRoBwdgEVEG52FcaA1Egq54jgYAUlIa8sQYERbAk9QiD7AEgjKCIiEOPwhRzJsTEXPx2hwfKoFK8qStWcrciwUo-WqwrisDWLFAgaZgCq9oAEYAAZSHDH4qqIWqahzCIoAAaigAbw2ybE0qDDKsr1HK8oK4AirgJZ6rKmpKravaOrUqa-Ca7BfXGs79sOzrFm63r+sWkaxuGCaoHag6ZvmqAAHIBqB5bsU0NAhEWaB92QoTDFCO8M3ic04BSNJek-CgcEdRYlkUIgwgAMl1V4crBUgiFQfk4CMOBsQRnBWt2x6cy6nr4ve4bRpZmqGumwNaNEUQRBIKrefuohnBFsW4BzAA5AW-AluhSEZnxmal37zv+56Dk5vqIkGz6+aunNhdFhI4Alr6hh+v6nrUpXjpViIkvVuggA)

Just wanted to share my two cents.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, you provide a great implementation. I have similar implementation to yours, but it doesn't work if using one `Array` parameter instead of using spread parameters.
I add some code below your code: http://shorturl.at/pwzIR